# Using two dynamic libraries in a static library projects

Tags: c++, linker, dynamic-library

I have two projects that are configured as dynamic libraries. Their output is a DLL and .lib files.
I am trying to do a new project to be used as a simple interface which in return uses both projects. I want the final output to be a static library if this is possible.

So far I did the following:

1. Added both projects to my solution and added them to my final interface's references
2. Added both directories for the header files that I will be using in my interface
3. Checked the Link Library Dependencies in the Librarian configuration

Finally my project was built successfully but when I tried using the output library (.lib file) I had several `unresolved external symbol` errors on run time and I do not know what I am missing

I also tried configuring my interface to be a dynamic library project, but this time when I build my project the same errors appear but on compile time

Comment: If you add dynamic libraries to your static library, then it's not really that static anymore - the client of the library will gain those dynamic dependencies. You can't turn a dynamic library into a static one just by linking it to a static library.

Comment: Static libraries do not carry dependency information in their built form beyond expected symbols. Whatever project is using the static library needs to explicitely link against the dynamic library as well.

Comment: @Frank And what about having a dynamic library based on both. Why did I have the unresolved external symbol errors although I added both projects to the linker